# How do I reinstall the software packages that came with Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: package-management, reinstall

I uninstalled several GNOME applications, LibreOffice apps and various other apps. How do I reinstall them all at one without having to reinstall the operating system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Installing the `ubuntu-desktop` package ought to pull the default packages.

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

Answer (score 4):

The default set of packages for 18.04 is listed in http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.manifest (for later releases, just go up to https://releases.ubuntu.com and navigate to the correct release/architecture for your situation).

You can obtain the package names only from this textfile via the following command:

```
curl http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.manifest | sed -e 's#\t.*##g'
```

Therefore, you should be able to install those packages by passing the output of that command to `apt install`:

```
# Ubuntu 18.04.1
sudo apt install $( curl http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.manifest | sed -e 's#\t.*##g' )
```

If you're using another version or architecture (arch=amd64 in the above commands), you'll need to modify your command accordingly.

Comment: I’d recommend the use of `xargs` over command substitution: `curl http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.manifest | sed -e 's#\t.*##g' | xargs sudo apt install`